# What are recommended directives for robots.txt in a Django application?

Tags: python, django, robots.txt

Currently my django project has following structure.

```
./
../ 
app1/
app2/
django_project
manage.py
media
static
secret_stuff
```

and my `robots.txt` looks something like this:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /
Sitemap: mysite.com/sitemaps.xml
```

I want to know following things:

1. What are the recommend directives should i add to my `robots.txt`
   file, as django documentation is saying nothing on this topic.
2. How do i stop bots from reaching (indexing) contents of
   `secret_stuff` and `mysite.com/admin/` directory ?

   ```
     Disallow: /secret_stuff      (Is that okay ?)
     Disallow: /admin            (Is that okay ?)
   ```

Comment: Why downvote ? please state reason

Answer (score 2):

Robots directives are not related to Django framework that is why you won't find any information about it in Django docs. Normally, it is up to you what to allow and what to disallow for searching on you website.

There are different ways to include robots.txt into the Django project. I am personally using **django-robots** app which simplifies the way you can embed robots.txt into you project.

It is not necessary to use it in every project. If you find it simpler you can just render txt file by yourself.

My simplified robots.txt for Django project looks like:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /*.pdf
Disallow: /*.ppt
Disallow: /*.doc
Disallow: /*.xls
Disallow: /*.txt

User-agent: Yandex
Allow: /events
Allow: /contests
Allow: /schools
Disallow: /admin
Crawl-delay: 3

User-agent: Googlebot
Allow: /events
Allow: /contests
Allow: /schools
Disallow: /admin
Crawl-delay: 3

Host: https://mysite.ru
Sitemap: https://mysite.ru/sitemap.xml
```