# what is robots.txt warning in django and advise to handle this?

Tags: python, django, web-crawler, robots.txt

I am running Django on localhost (development machine), and I came across this in my debug console:

```
Not Found: /robots.txt
2018-03-20 22:58:03,173 WARNING Not Found: /robots.txt
[20/Mar/2018 22:58:03] "GET /robots.txt HTTP/1.1" 404 18566
```

What is the meaning of this and if there is any recommendation to handle this right. Also on production server.

Comment: unless this is a publicly visible site, you would not be seeing this request. If it's a publicly visible site, you should not be running the development server

Answer (score 5, accepted):

robots.txt is a standard for web crawlers, such as those used by search engines, that tells them which pages they should index.

To resolve the issue, you can either host your own version of robots.txt statically, or use a package like [django-robots](https://github.com/jazzband/django-robots).

It's odd that you're seeing the error in development unless you or your browser is trying to explicitly access it.

In production, if you're concerned with SEO, you'll likely also want to set up the webmaster tools with each search engine , example: [Google Webmaster Tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/home?hl=en)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062608?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

`robots.txt` is a file that is used to manage behavior of crawling robots (such as search index bots like google). It determines which paths/files the bots should include in it's results. If things like search engine optimization are not relevant to you, don't worry about it.

If you do care, you might want to use a django native implementation of robots.txt file management like [this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-robots).

Answer (score 0):

the **robots.txt** file is a *Robots exclusion standard*, please see **[THIS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robots_exclusion_standard)** for more informtion.

Here is an example of Google's robots.txt: https://www.google.com/robots.txt

For a good example of how to set one up, use [What are recommended directives for robots.txt in a Django application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594231/what-are-recommended-directives-for-robots-txt-in-a-django-application), as reference.

Comment: thanks, i see in the link has this. what are these configuration in robots.txt , .ru are illegal sites ? ---->
Host: https://mysite.ru
Sitemap: https://mysite.ru/sitemap.xml

Comment: Host: Is your site | and Sitemap: is the location of the **xml** for your site that includes all the available pages, usually for google to index your site. If you're small and don't care about your `pagerank` then you need not worry about that.

Comment: Those are just example sites, not for actual use, use your domain.